# problem with function call in c++

Tags: c++, function, program-entry-point

I have a problem with my program, I work actually on interpolation with Cubic BSplines, but when I call my interpolate function in main() I get a wrong result, and when I write directly the function in main() it works :(.
I can not see what is the difference between the both.

```
void CubicBSpline::interpolation(){
  Point3d point;
  for(unsigned int i = 3; i < (knots->m_points).size(); i++){
    for(double t=0; t<1; t+=0.1){
      point = bSplineCubicUniform(i, t);
      cout << point.x << " " << point.y <<endl;
    }
  }
}

int main(){
  CubicBSpline cbs(4, 4);
  cbs.interpolation(); //this is the call of my function but I got a wrong result

  // and here I write directly my function and that's work good
  Point3d point;
  for(unsigned int i = 3; i < (cbs.knots->m_points).size(); i++){
    for(double t=0; t<1; t+=0.1){
      point = cbs.bSplineCubicUniform(i, t);
      cout << point.x << " " << point.y <<endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong result"?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code... may be is for example a problem with uninitialized variables. What happens if you move the `cbs.interpolation` call AFTER the explicit calls in main?

Comment: And by the way, that's a method not a function!

Comment: And it would be helpful to see the global variables.

Comment: @Amokrane: Methods are functions.

Comment: @Simone: this function use a set of points, in  first time I use 4 points, so the interpolation representation must be between the second and the third point, but when I call my function, it give me an other result.

Comment: @6502: I'd try your suggestion, it give the same wrong result :(.

Comment: @Amokrane: If you want to be pedantic, it's a *member function*, a type of *function*. In C++, there is no such thing as a method.

Comment: @CHAKRI: Telling us "it gives me another result" is completely meaningless. Let's say I came to you and said "my car's broken" and you asked "well, what's wrong with it?" and I said "it's not working like I expect", do you really suppose it's reasonable for you to even *try* to solve my problem? You need to tell us what you expect, what you're getting instead, and what your program is, how we can reproduce the results, and what you've tried.

Comment: @GMan : can you explain me what is the difference between the two ways   of use of my function 'interpolation'?

Comment: @CHAKRI: Not without a full source code listing. Note by full we mean all the related code, you can strip the unrelated stuff. (Unless we suspect it's there, then we'll ask, and you can add it.)

Comment: @CHAKRI: There is no difference in the two ways,... the difference is that some member variables have a different state after calling `bSplineCubicUniform` ... at least thats my suspicion. could you give us a listing of `bSplineCubicUniform` and the ctor of CubicBSpline ?

Comment: @GMan: C++ has methods.  The standard calls them member functions, but speaking only standardese is rarely helpful.

Comment: I found the origin of the error, it's Point3d, in my exemple I use it like that:
struct Point3d{ double x, y, z};
I replaced it with a vector<double> and thats work.

but I don't know what is the problem with Point3d.

Comment: @Fred: The domain of my response was that within pedantry.

Comment: @GMan: Useless pedantry is useless.

Comment: @Fred: Didn't say it was useful. Do you have a point to make, or are you just trying to sound like a big-boy?

Comment: @GMan: You make a statement that you nearly admit is useless, then ask why I call you out on it?  Were you *trying* to add to the noise?

Comment: @Fred: What do you mean "call out"? You can't call me out on something I never claimed. My response was to Amokrane's attempt at pedantry, nothing more. Yes, his attempt wasn't useful in the general case, so neither was mine, but it wasn't *intended* to be. This isn't that difficult to grasp.

Comment: @GMan: Given the nicest interpretation possible to his and your comments, I can see Amokrane being confused by terminology, but I can't see your comment being useful.  I explained why in my first comment to you.  Comments which aren't even *intended* to be useful are better left unsaid.

Comment: @Fred: Not useful *to anyone but Amokrane*. He obviously cares about terminology, so why not help him out with the correct terminology? If you don't care about terminology, then my comment isn't for you.

Answer (score 3):

Your description is decidedly uninformative (and it seems you'd rather respond with abrasive comments than provide more information) so all I can give you is a general answer. A bunch of things could be different between these two cases. Firstly presumably these two functions are defined within different files therefore depending on what's included different types could have entirely different definitions. From what I can see you don't have any scoping problems, but maybe I'm wrong. And also since you don't provide us with code for these other functions who knows what side effects they have.

However honestly I think that your problem most likely is due to an optimization that the compiler makes when the function is inlined. (Try compiling without optimizations).

Finally the most glaringly bad thing here is that you have a loop that uses a double as its iterator... are you kidding me? Who knows how many times that loop get's executed. It's entirely dependent on the compiler's floating point round off, which means not only is it unpredictable, but even if you get lucky and it works on your machine, who knows if it will work on other ones.

Comment: There's a decent answer in here, hidden under the distracting negative tone.

Comment: The solution to the floating point problem would be to use an integer counter `i` (in this case from 0 to 10) and then pass `i * 0.1` to the function.